# Print write and comment into .gdbinit file

Tags: gdb

Is there any way how to write comment into gdb file?

`b*0x1111 # break point at function`
or
`b*0x1111 // break point at function`
or `b*0x1111 ; break point at function`
That return an error .

Or maybe is there a way to print for screen output like

`write('hi!')` or `display('hi!')` doesn't work

Comment: for printing you can use `echo`

Comment: For comments, try putting `# comment` on a separate line.